# No longer able to use bundleReleaseAar in MavenPublication

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading Gradle to 5.1.1, I found that I'm unable to add `bundleReleaseAar` as an artifact to my MavenPublication. Here's the relevant snippet of my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            version libraryVersion
            artifactId libraryArtifactId

            artifact bundleReleaseAar
            //artifact sourcesJar
            //artifact packageJavadoc
        }
    }
}
```

This fails with:

`Could not get unknown property 'bundleReleaseAar' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication.`

However, I am able to see that `bundleReleaseAar` does indeed exist when I run `./gradlew tasks`, and I can execute that task just fine.

What is preventing it from being used as an artifact in my deployment now?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Short Answer :**

You need to enclose the publishing {} block inside a project.afterEvaluate as follows:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            aar(MavenPublication) {
                groupId libraryGroupId
                version libraryVersion
                artifactId libraryArtifactId

                artifact bundleReleaseAar
                //artifact sourcesJar
                //artifact packageJavadoc
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Long Answer :**

Prior to gradle version 4.8, publishing block was implicitly treated as if all the logic inside it was executed after the project was evaluated. This was only block that behaved this way and this behavior was discontinued post gradle version 4.8 for consistency's sake. bundleReleaseAar task seems to be available only after project evaluation is complete and therefore to maintain behavior it must be explicitly enclosed inside project.afterEvaluate{}

Reference : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel4.8:deferred_configuration

Comment: Wrapping in `afterEvaluate` does not work for me, is there something else I'm missing? Perhaps a plugin I did not apply?

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.library' and apply plugin: 'maven-publish' should be the only plugins you need. What error are you getting? Are you working in an Android library?

Comment: Could not get unknown property 'bundleReleaseAar'. I am working in an android library yes.

Comment: actually `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` was the problem. I had my publishing code in the project build.gradle. It works in the library module build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

I fix this problem change artifact from:

```
artifact bundleReleaseAar
```

to:

```
artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
```

this help me Gradle sync success, but i must call assembleRelease directly, before `./gradlew publish`

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a working manual way. Issue of this is there is no longer a dependency between the MavenPublication task and the build, so calling `./gradlew publish` will not rebuild the project.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by calling the artifact function into the afterEvaluate closure, the issue is that the artifact function does not handle all the configuration lazily

```
publishing {
   publications {
      aar(MavenPublication) {
        groupId libraryGroupId
        version libraryVersion
        artifactId libraryArtifactId
        afterEvaluate {
           artifact bundleReleaseAar
           //artifact sourcesJar
           //artifact packageJavadoc
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Reference https://github.com/moberwasserlechner/capacitor-oauth2/issues/10

Answer (score 0):

If you have several flavors then you need to use bundle<your_flavor_name>ReleaseAar